# c# getting the project name within an assembly

Tags: c#

I need to find a way to get the class file name that an exception will be thrown in. 
for example the project's tree structure would be

```
SchoolCourses (assembly name)
->GraduatePrograms.cs
->UndergraduatePrograms.cs
->CommunityPrograms.cs 
->SchoolCourseMain.cs
```

I have tried System.Reflection:

```
return "ERROR:\n An error has occurred in " + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

output: 
    ERROR:
    An error has occurred in SchoolCourses
```

However, that is returning the project name, I would like it to be more along the lines of

```
output: 
    ERROR:
    An error has occurred in SchoolCourses.GraduatePrograms
```

Comment: Is there some reason the StackTrace on the exception object is insufficient?

Comment: The stack trace contains file name and line number of the source code file.  It is retrieved from the .pdb file that the compiler generates.   *Never* avoid displaying it, this info is absolutely crucial to debugging a problem.  Always favor using the exception's ToString() method to get the best info, it also won't skip the essential InnerException.  Right now you are just doing it wrong and you asked this question because you start to find out you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative might be to use `Environment.StackTrace` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> The StackTrace property formats the stack trace information for each method call as follows:
>
> "at FullClassName.MethodName(MethodParams) in FileName :line LineNumber "

Comment: i wasn't aware of the stack trace. But if it contains all the information i need, and more, then it looks like the ideal option.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `this.GetType().Name`

```
return "ERROR:\n An error has occurred in " + this.GetType().Name;
```

Comment: Of course this is the type name not the file name, so you'd lose the .cs, and it assumes your class matches your file name.